# How to make an array from items in textarea separated by a new line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a textarea with the id `#list` :

```
$text = $('#list').val();
```

and I need to explode and create this text into pieces and each of the piece put as a new item in an array, so, I can send this array to PHP and use it in a foreach loop (I hope that the array will be the same in PHP and ajax will not make a json or string from it again ;)

Btw. the list are urls so I was thinking to separate them by a new line od `http://` or a blank space?

How to do that?

UPDATE:

So, when I get the value from textarea like this:

```
var listURLs = $('#list').val();
```

When I insert something like this in my textarea:

```
asdfasd

adsf





fr
f
```

to the PHP via ajax if I do this in PHP:

```
$listURLs = $_POST['listURLs'];

$arrayURLs = explode("\r\n", $listURLs);

print_r($arrayURLs);

die();
```

I will get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => asdfasd

    adsf





    fr
    f
)
```

Answer (score 4):

in your php you can do

```
$lines = explode("\r\n", $_POST['list']);
```

and in jquery

```
var lines = $('textarea[name=list]').val().split('\n');
```

Comment: Thanks, what is faster?

Comment: The php is not working. it creates only one item in array and I have put multiple nw lines in the textarea `Array
(
    [0] => asdfasdfasdf
as
df
asdf
a
sdf
asdf

)` It seems that the Javascript is removing new lines and sending it as spaces to php? Because if I print_r() in PHP the send item, there is only one entry in the array.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's this ? `dataType: 'json', data : { action : 'import_urls', lines: lines},` ? dataType json can be doing problems?

Comment: can you post your html and jquery ?

Comment: Check my updated question for more info. Only [0] is created no more like [1] and [2] and other keys.

Comment: can you show me the text you but it inside your textarea input

Comment: it's in my update , check the second gray area with the input

Comment: Any idea? Why is explode not splitting it into an array like it shoud. Did ajax remove the new lines?

Comment: How to exlode it based on a one or more spaces instead of new line. It seems that ajax or my server is messing things and the safest bet wil be a space between strings `http://example.com http://example2.com http://example3.com` ... you get that idea. How to do that in php?